# Webpack plugin to modify a file before and after compilation

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin

I'm trying to build a webpack plugin that does a simple thing, replace a string in a file before webpack compiles everything, and place that string back after the compilation.

A configuration would look like this:

```
{
   files: ['myFile.js'],
   replace: 'myString'
}
```

Basically I don't want webpack to see `myString`, so I replace it with some unique string and then put `myString` back, after webpack compiles everything. The plugins/loaders named in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46230376/982921) don't fit my use case.

I think a loader is not needed, because I know what files have to change so I don't need to analyze each file.

I've read the doc about plugins but I'm still kinda lost and probably doing a very inefficient plugin. Maybe someone with experience with plugins can guide me.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't see [string-replace-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-webpack-plugin) in the linked answer. We use this to replace strings that need to change based on which environment they are deployed to. You can use the `test` key to limit to the filename that contains the string you want to change.

Example from their README:

```
loaders: [
     // configure replacements for file patterns 
     { 
        test: /index.html$/,
        loader: StringReplacePlugin.replace({
            replacements: [
                {
                    pattern: /<!-- @secret (\w*?) -->/ig,
                    replacement: function (match, p1, offset, string) {
                        return secrets.web[p1];
                    }
                }
            ]})
        }
]
```

We do something simple like:

```
{
    pattern: /_GOOGLE_ID_//ig,
    replacement: function (match, p1, offset, string) {
        return 'my-actual-google-id-for-this-env';
    }
}
```

Comment: `string-replace loader` is different than `string-replace-webpack`